# Find and group duplicates in str Python

Tags: python, string, difflib

I have a column in my dataframe with the list of words that look alike. I want to create a group column, in order to put in the same group the words which look alike based on the string matching with difflib but without using the for loop, because I have 800k row.

I have a database that looks like this:

```
Df['col']

'atr.i'
'atr i',
'ok',
'test'
'ro bn.',
'ro bn',
'talk 1',
'talk n'
```

I want to create a new column that group of database with difflib.

Expected output

```
'atr.i', 1
'atr i', 1
'ok',
'test'
'ro bn.', 2
'ro bn', 2
'talk 1', 3
'talk n', 3
```

Comment: OP wants to check all data for similar text in a many-to-many relationship. Not sure if there's a faster than O(n^2) solution. If there is, this is a very good question.

Comment: Yes, can you post sample please N

Comment: Don't think there is a better than `O(n^2)` solution. We'll have to let other people have a chance solving this.

Comment: Is the pattern of strings allways something like `keyword/delimiter/*`, where keyword is e.g. `atr`, `ro` and delimiter is `.` or white space? If that is the case there is a solution in O(2N)

Comment: Not always something like keyword/delimiter/

Answer (score 1):

I maybe did not get all details of the question. Also there is only one short example given. Therefore I needed to make some assumptions.  The following code might be used as starting point:

```
import re


def find_group(data):
    groups = {}
    next_id = 1
    for d in data:
        dsplit = re.split(r"[\. ]", d)
        if len(dsplit) == 2:
            if dsplit[0] not in groups:
                groups[dsplit[0]] = next_id
                next_id += 1
    return groups


def output_data(df, groups):
    for d in df:
        dsplit = re.split(r"[\. ]", d)
        if dsplit[0] in groups:
            print("'%s', %d" % (d, groups[dsplit[0]]))
        else:
            print("'%s'" % (d, ))
        

def main():

    Df = [ 'atr.i', 'atr i', 'ok', 'test', 'ro bn.',
           'ro bn', 'talk 1', 'talk n' ]
    groups = find_group(Df)
    output_data(Df, groups)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which provides the expected result:

```
$ python3 group.py 
'atr.i', 1
'atr i', 1
'ok'
'test'
'ro bn.', 2
'ro bn', 2
'talk 1', 3
'talk n', 3
```

Comment: instead of using a `in groups` you could also store the group names in a dictionary and then do the `dict.get` lookup with `None` as default value which is probably faster. (Especially if the original list has 800k entries)

Comment: The function `find_group()` takes less than 1sec for 800k input. Not sure if an optimization is needed.

Comment: @Adreas `if dsplit[0] in groups:`  is the comparison that I was refering to. But I just realized that `groups` already is a dict. Nevertheless the `if` statement could be replaced by `groups.get(dsplit[0], None)`, basically does the conditional internally.